# Apache Solr, SolrJ vs Data Import Handler for parsing XML

Tags: java, xml, solr, solrj, dih

I'm hoping to use Solr to run searches from info parsed from XML files.
These XML files are not in Solr's document format, as such I have to parse them and get the fields I need that way.

I am familiar with Java programming and was wondering if SolrJ would be an easier method than using the Data Import Handler. I'm considering running through each XML file I have and parsing the fields that I need from each. Is there any downside to one method over the other? I imagine since I have familiarity with Java it may be easier to parse the XML that way?

I will probably need multiple conditions and regular expressions. If anything, a reliable way to get my fields from relatively unstructured XML.

How would SolrJ work with the interface? That is, if I index using SolrJ, can I do my queries through the interface still?

Answer (score 3):

DIH was designed for prototyping, though some people do use it for production. You can start from it, but be ready to jump to SolrJ or other methods if you hit its limitations. And if you have very complex mappings, you may be better off with SolrJ to start from.

You can also [apply XSLT transform on an incoming XML document](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html) to map it to the Solr format.

And as said elsewhere, search is a separate issue from indexing.

Answer (score 1):

How you index your content into Solr is orthogonal to how you query it. You can index any way you want, as long as it produces the right docs in the index.

Now, regarding indexing, if DIH will get what you need without much tweaking go for it. But if you need to do a lot of tweaking of the data, in the end you might finish faster if you just write some java with Solr. With Solr you have all the flexibility, with DIH you are more constrained (think of the 80/20 rule).

Comment: And DIH is probably faster than adding every document with SorlJ